# Fixing Power BI Parameters in the service

Tags: parameters, powerbi

How do i ***fix*** the values of the parameters in the PBI service so they do not change the next time I deploy the report.

I'm using parameters for the datasource, and on my desktop the server datasource  is `(local)`.  I've deployed the report to the service and changed the parameter to `somethingNotLocal.whatevs.net`.

When I next deploy the report, the parameter gets changed back to `(local)`

do you know of way that publishing the report will not update the parameters set on the service?

Answer (score 1):

The parameter is updated because you publish a new report that updates it.

I believe that the parameters are exposed in Power BI Service not long ago to somehow achieve what you're trying to do (switching data source connection without redeploying the .pbix file). Before that, you can only change parameters in Power BI Desktop or through API.

You can check out a relevant community post here:

[Using the Power BI Service Parameters to change connection strings (To possibly change between Dev,](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Community-Blog/Using-the-Power-BI-Service-Parameters-to-change-connection/ba-p/392016)

So what you can do is either not changing the parameter in the first place, or update it in Power BI Service after publishing.

Or you can suggest your more advanced use case in [Power BI Ideas](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas).